# Why can I not get my components back out of JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I have extended the JPanel class with some additional functionality I require, and I then created an instance of it like so:

```
CustomPanel pan = new CustomPanel();
```

I then add it to my to my frame:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(pan);
```

I then need to the panel back off the frame, I do this like so:

```
for (Component c : frame.getComponents())
{
    if(c instanceof CustomPanel)
    {
        System.out.println("Should get here");
    }       
}
```

But it doesn't exist in memory as a CustomPanel, instead it exists as a JPanel, why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, the JFrame contains a JPanel, when you add your custom Panel to the JFrame using getContentPane().add(pan), you're actually adding your custom panel to the JFrame's JPanel. I'm guessing you'll have to call frame.getContentPane().getComponents(); to iterate over the components contained in the JFrame's panel.

Comment: +1 See [Using Top Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) for a more detailed look at the strucuture of a JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

Your for should read:

```
for (Component c : frame.getContentPane().getComponents())
```

You didn't add your Panel to the frame, you added it to the content pane.

Comment: -1,this suggestion was made earlier. No need to clutter the forum with duplicate answers.